# how to insert a nested 2d array in database in laravel using realtionship

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, orm

I am trying to save the Home model with its realation ship called Phone  that I want to insert unlimited Phones for it . Now I am inserting home without any problem but when it comes to phone I can't insert my 2d array into phone ! Here is my controller :

```
 $validated = $request->all();
    if (!$validated) {
        return $this->sendError('Validation Error.', $validated->errors());
    }

    $home = Home::create($validated);
    $phones = $request->input('phones');
    for ($i =0; $i < count($phones); $i++) {
        $insertPhone[$i] = json_decode($phones[$i]);
    }
    dd($insertPhone);
    $home->phones()->createMany($insertPhone);
    return new HomeResource($home);
```

and down there is the dd result of $insertPhone :

```
 array:2 [
  0 => {#533
    +"value": "123"
    +"is_attachment": "true"
  }
  1 => {#538
    +"value": "456"
    +"is_attachment": "true"
  }
]
```

Comment: What specifically goes wrong?

Comment: Why do you use `json_decode` ? I suppose phones come from inputs ?

Comment: @VincentDecaux its an api so it comes in body as parameter i think

Comment: @showdev it wont insert any thing just null rows

Answer (score 0):

`createMany` expects a multidimensional array with key / value, for example :

```
$home->phones()->createMany([
    [
        'number' => '049230323432',
    ],
    [
        'number' => '432094249023',
    ],
]);
```

So you should do like :

```
$phones = $request->input('phones');
$insertPhone = [];
foreach ($phones as $phone) {
    $insertPhone []= [
        'number' => $phone,
    ];
}
```

Comment: but consider what i am reciving from my front is like below :

Comment: phones=[
{"value":"21351321" , "is_attachment":"true"}
]

Comment: Oh yes sorry didn't check the dd in your post. It seems ok, is your $home well set after the create ? your relation works ?

Comment: yes it works i checked that out when i enter it as hard code data will be inserted